# Call ASP.NET WEB API method with post parameter from classic ASP

Tags: asp.net-web-api

How to call ASP.NET WEBAPI method from classic asp by sending post data and recevie data in xml format?

Below is the code written for this implementation:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string data)
    {
        var rspdata= data;

        return new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent(rspdata, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
        };
    }

    Set HttpReq = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    HttpReq.open "post", "api/conenter code heretrollername", False
    HttpReq.send data="hello"
```

Please help out me, it's not wokring as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make a web request from classic asp. As far as I realize the problem is that whenever you make the request you need to use proper headers. Unless you change the model binder of asp.net web api, it will only accept application/xml or application/json for post method. Once you post xml or JSON it will try to deserialize to your Model that you defined in web api side. In this case you must create a new RequestDTO and modify your method like below:

```
public class RequestDTO{

    public string Data {get; set;}

}

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] RequestDTO reqObj)
{
    var rspdata= reqObj.Data;

    return new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        Content = new StringContent(rspdata, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
    };
}
```

In order to execute this method from ASP side, you need to serialize your post data as JSON or XML. I'm giving the JSON below:

```
{ "data" : "test" }
```

and last but not least you should set your `Content-Type : application/json` and `Accept:application/xml` (only if you need XML as a response from Web API side)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi ,I tried to execute the above method using fiddler but RequestDTO  is alwasy empty

Comment: I am executing the above method using fiddler

Comment: have you set the headers? There must be problems with your request headers.

Comment: No , am setting the headers to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.Even then its the data is empty

Comment: Hi,I have used fiddler to diagnoise the issue User-Agent: Fiddler 
User-Agent: Fiddler
Accept: application/json
Content-type: application/json
Host: localhost:2371
Content-Length: 9


{"Data":"4"}

now i am able to see the posted data in controller method, now i tried to to the same to return xml format insted of json                     User-Agent: Fiddler
Accept: application/xml
Content-type: application/xml
Host: localhost:2371
Content-Length: 11



Data = 4           This peice of code is not working . Please help me

Comment: Instead of returning httpresponsemessage, could you please try to return directly string or object, that you want to.

Comment: Hi Sir, Its not working Can you pelase help me out i dont undertstand y its not working. Please provide me working sample with fiddler screenshot . Please